# Valid use cases for at-sign in php

Tags: php

The at sign is used to hide error messages. As far as I see, there is absolutely no use case or excuse for using it.

1. You can hide errors in production by changing php ini settings while still outputting errors to log files
2. @-sign makes it difficult for fellow programmers to identify where the problem is
3. Error messages are your friends when you are developing. Find errors fast and fix them

A friend of mine just spent a couple of hours trying to find out why the software works on one system and not on another. This would have taken about 10 seconds if the library developer wouldn't have used @-sign.

Am I close-minded when I say that there is absolutely no value to @-sign, is there a valid case?

Comment: Tell your friend to look at the [scream extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/scream); it makes the `@` useless, which means *all* errors are always reported. Saved me a couple of hours, a couple of times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is some value to the @ sign, but it's normally a code smell.
Consider the following: you're developing a library that needs to be compatible with multiple projects, and you don't want to change the error handler globally. Unfortunately, many PHP functions (including the sockets and streams related ones) throw a PHP error rather than an exception on failure. The "@" sign is then useful for hiding the error *if and only if* the error is then checked for manually and an exception is thrown if it occurred. 
It's also useful for filesystem operations.
Mainly you're right though...it's normally terrible practice (:

Comment: I'm so used to having my own error handler, that I didn't even think of that there might be situations where you don't want to create a global error handler. Thank you

Comment: Be aware that even in situations where the return code is checked, using `@` can introduce debugging "fun". Just think of a PHP extension which for some reason is not loaded. `@` suppresses the "undefined function" PHP fatal error and the script will terminate without any hint.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few rare situations where it indeed makes sense to use error suppression.

One of them are atomic filesystem operations. E.g. instead of writing

```
if (file_exists($fileName)) {
    unlink($fileName);
}
```

you just do

```
@unlink($fileName);
```

This makes sure that your code is not subject to race conditions.

Generally `@` is useful in situations where *PHP chose an inappropriate error model* for a function. The above `unlink` function is one such example. Similarly there are other functions where PHP throws errors, even though it shouldn't (instead using return values or catchable exceptions).

Comment: For many of those you can (should?) create a custom error handler that converts php errors into exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases you should indeed not use it. Some cases it makes sense though:

- `unlink()`
- `while (@ob_end_flush());`

There might be some other edge cases, but besides these you should really never ever supress errors.

Answer (score 0):

As with all tools available (both in programming and outside of it), everything has a legitimate use case.

The first example that comes to mind for the error suppression operator would be something like

```
if (!@unlink($file)) {
    // I am already handling the error. I don't care what caused it.
    // Even NOT handling this case at all could be a legitimate reaction
    // depending on circumstances.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- When using `DOMDocument`, invalid HTML will throw warnings, we don't care on most cases.
- When using PEAR's `Mail`, you'll get warnings about functions that shouldn't be called statically, that's because `Mail` supports PHP 4. These can be safely ignored.
- When using `unlink()`, you suppress errors to prevent race conditions.

Comment: For the first one: I put the initialization inside a try-catch and if necessary, do something with the error

Answer (score 0):

The most common place I have seen it used is for suppressing mysql errors when working with a db. Then the user checks the response instead and prints an appropriate error message.

Example

```
<?php
$link = @mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

I have also seen it used when working with ftps and sftps.

But I agree with you that I find its uses limited. If one ends up in a situation where one feels the need to use the @-sign at own produced code, I think it's time to rethink the solution.

Comment: I just said that this is the type of uses I have seen it used in. Google "php mysql" or something and quite a few use this type of code. But I agree, the existence of @ is almost not justified at all.

Comment: Well in all honestly OP asked about *valid* use cases :)