# php file is writable but cannot be deleted

Tags: php, unlink

I am using this function. is_file and is_writable return true, but when I true to unlink, it gives an error. This is on windows server.

```
if(is_file($fileToDelete)) {
  if(is_writable($fileToDelete)) {
    unlink($fileToDelete);
  }
}
```

The file is a PDF document, which I have open. I thought is_writable would return false in this case, but it doesn't.

So how can I tell if a file can be deleted or not?

Thank you

Comment: do you have permissions to modify it ? Right-click it and check it's properties

Comment: Close the file before you try to delete it

Comment: Yes, because if I close the file, I can unlink it just fine from php.

Comment: Thank you, Musa, but the whole point is to not attempt to delete files that are open by other users. I know I have the file open because I am testing it. In the real world, I will not know if a file is open or not, that is why I need a way to test if it can be deleted before I attempt to unlink it.

Comment: How are you serving the files, via a web-server?

Comment: Via network share, but the solution PeeHaa suggested seems to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about doing it the other way around? Just try to delete the file and check whether it is really gone?

```
@unlink($fileToDelete);

if(is_file($fileToDelete)) {
   // file was locked (or permissions error)
}
```

Not sure whether this is workable in your specific case though, but judging by the code in your question this should be what you want.

Comment: Thank you! This may show my inexperience, but what exactly does prefixing a function call with @ do? Thanks again, this worked.

Comment: @user1560676 It suppresses errors. So even if the unlinking spits out errors it will not be displayed. However please note that there are only a couple of cases where you should use `@`  and this is one of them. Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12053897/valid-use-cases-for-at-sign-in-php/12053971) about its use. Whatever you do don't ever use it as a silver bullet to get rid of errors.

Comment: @user1560676 http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php, it is the error suppression operator. It tells php to ignore any errors that derive from that line. Generally it is frowned upon to use it, but there are some legit uses such as this.

Comment: Why not rely on the return code of `unlink`? - `if (!@unlink($fileToDelete)) { throw new Exception('Unable to delete file!'); }`

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the file? I mean, did you open it by doing fopen($file)?

Do a fclose($file) before trying to delete the file.

Comment: Jorge - I am not using the file from php. These are PDF documents that users could have open on their desktop by mistake while trying to re-generate them. That is what I need to check... if the file is open elsewhere and cannot be deleted by php.

Answer (score 0):

For them who don't want to delete the file before the check, the solution is here :

```
$file = "test.pdf";

if (!is_file($file)) {
    print "File doesn't exist.";
} else {
    $fh = @fopen($file, "r+");
    if ($fh) {
        print "File is not opened and seems able to be deleted.";
        fclose($fh);
    } else {
        print "File seems to be opened somewhere and can't be deleted.";
    }
}
```

Simple, and efficient.

Comment: That is good if, for instance, you want to let the user know if a file can be deleted or not and then present them with the option to do so. Good post.