# how delete All files except one in folder with php?

Tags: php, image, file

i have this php code to delete all images file in folder, but i need to keep example.php file.

how i can?

```
$dir = @opendir('../result_image/');
while (false !== ($file = @readdir($dir)))
{
    if ($file != '..' && $file != '.')
    {
    $upload[] = $file;
    }
}

$time_sec=@time();
    for($i=0;$i<count($upload);$i++)
    {
    $time_file=@filemtime('../result_image/'.$upload[$i]);
    $time=$time_sec-$time_file;
if($time>9000)
    {
        //if ($upload[] = "disk_save.php") continue;
        @unlink('../result_image/'.$upload[$i]);
      }
   }
```

**I have 3 answer for my questions and all of them can work.but witch of them is best ? this code execute every time users upload picture.**

Comment: Why are you suppressing (`@`) almost all of the functions in your script?

Comment: Do all of the images you want to delete have the same extension? _A side note about suppressing function calls: it slows down execution time considerably if you suppress most/all of your calls._

Comment: my dear, i have disk_save.php in this folder. i don't want delete this file in execution.

Comment: @user3425550 Please define best =). All answers works. To my mind you should define which is more maintainable in the futur and adapt to your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code works for me too,
i put .php name file in **IF** before put another file in $upload[]. like this:

```
$dir = opendir('../result_image/');
while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir)))
{
    if ($file != 'disk_save.php')
    {
    $upload[] = $file;
    }
}
$time_sec=time();
for($i=0;$i<count($upload);$i++)
{
$time_file=filemtime('../result_image/'.$upload[$i]);
$time=$time_sec-$time_file;
    if($time>9000)
    {
        //if($upload[$i] != 'disk_save.php'){
        unlink('../result_image/'.$upload[$i]);
        //}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it as follows.

```
$time_sec=time();
$excludeFiles = array('example.php','disk_save.php');
for($i=0;$i<count($upload);$i++)
{
    $time_file=filemtime('../result_image/'.$upload[$i]);
    $time=$time_sec-$time_file;
    if($time>9000)
    {
        try {
            if (!in_array($upload[$i], $excludeFiles))
                unlink('../result_image/'.$upload[$i]);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // Error handle here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by add a simple `if` condition before `unlink` function like below.

```
//Your code here    
if($upload[$i] != 'example.php'){
    unlink('../result_image/'.$upload[$i]);
}
```

Note : adding `@` in-front of function is not a good practice try to overcome all bugs if occurs.

Comment: In case of `unlink` it [makes perfectly sense](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12053971/508666) though to use the STFU operator. You just need to check whether the files are really deleted afterwards.

Comment: this is best for me, because i have one .php file in my folder.

Comment: Dear Manibharathi, without @ after some time execute, i have some error about no file or no such as file for files witch delete already?can help me?

Comment: @user3425550 you can simply check file exist or not, before unlink the file like this `if(file_exists('example.php')){//unlink code}`.

Answer (score 0):

Explode each values stored in upload. I guess you have the whole name of the file:

```
$unwantedExt = array('php');
for($i=0;$i<count($upload);$i++) {
    list($fileName, $extension) = explode('.', $upload[$i]);
    if(!in_array($extension, $unwantedExt)) {
       unlink('../result_image/'.$upload[$i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `glob()` to iterate through all of the files in the target directory.  Additionally, if you only want to delete *(for instance)* `*.png` files, you can add the extension to the `glob()` call to be more efficient *(as well as ensuring you only delete image files as you mentioned)*.

---

```
    <?php

    $excluded = array('example.php', 'disk_save.php', 'some-other-file.php', ); //files to skip over, see comment below

    //if all of the images you want to delete have the same extension, it would be wise to
    //limit your iteration to only files with that extension:
    //  glob("../result_image/*.png")
    //If you want to delete multiple extensions:
    //  glob("../result_image/*.{png,jpg}", GLOB_BRACE)
    //Additionally, the `if (in_array(... continue;` statement becomes unnecessary and can be commented 
    //out or removed (assuming you added an extension to glob()). 
    foreach(glob("../result_image/*") as $fn) {
      if (in_array(basename($fn), $excluded)) //skip over excluded files
        continue; //see comment above

      $time_sec = time(); //if you are not working with a large number of image files, this line should be
                          //moved out of the foreach loop, to reduce execution time.
      $time_file = filemtime($fn);

      //check age of $fn and remove if it is old enough to be deleted
      if ($time_sec - $time_file > 9000) {
        unlink($fn);
      }
    }
```